# PHP - Login form not working in IE8

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication

I've just uncovered a rather annoying IE8 problem affecting a login page I'm working with. The login form is working correctly in FF (3.6 - MAC & PC), Chrome, Safari but does the equivalent of a refresh when you submit the UN/PW in IE8. No error, just a blank form looking me in the face.

**PHP code on the login page:**

```
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include 'includes/connect.php';

session_name('tzLogin');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['tzRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
}

if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{   
    $err = array();

    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'Sorry, all the fields must be completed.';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr,permission,fullName FROM adidas_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['fullName'] = $row['fullName'];
            $_SESSION['permission'] = $row['permission'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Opps, wrong username and/or password.';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);

    header("Location: dashboard.php");
    exit;
}
else {
}

$script = '';

?>
```

**Login related code on the 'dashboard' (landing) page:**

```
<?php
session_name('tzLogin');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
include 'includes/connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

**Finally, the form code:**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="contactForm" id="loginForm">
                <?php
                    if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])
                    {
                        echo '<div class="error">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</div>';
                        unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
                    }
                ?>
                <table class="loginTable" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                    <th width="50"><label for="username">Username:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="validate[required] textBox" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th><label for="password">Password:</label></th>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="validate[required] textBox" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <td style="padding-top:5px;"><input type="image" src="images/button_login.gif" alt="Login" name="submit" value="Login" /><span class="remember"><input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" />Remember me</span></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

The only thing I can think of/find is that IE8 doesn't handle cookies very well. That said, I checked to see what cookies are being set and I'm told that tzLogin is (with an expiry date which is ages away).

Note: My login page is based off this > http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/

Hoping someone can help with this frustration!

rrfive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE is not passing `submit=Login` only passing the coordinates for your image button (`submit.x` and `submit.y` values).

Store a hidden input instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitaction" value="Login" />
```

And in your PHP code:

```
if($_POST['submitaction']=='Login')
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, although I'd go for a javascript solution, because of it being less hassle in the long run.
Injecting the hidden input when on IE only, will also not dirtify the DOM for other sane browsers. 
Progressive destruction.